# Nginx request port

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have an nginx server with SSL enabled. As it operates on a different port (than 443), sometimes it receives plain HTTP requests instead of HTTPS. I'd like to set up a redirection for that to replace the scheme automatically, I tried this code:

```
error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
```

But the problem here that as the server operates in a VM and the port is forwarded to a different port, it redirects to an invalid port (from which the server got the request).

My question is: how can I parse/get the port from the request rather than the port from the server received the request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hopefully not too little too (eight months!) late. I had a similar question myself, to use the original request port in nginx.conf.

[nginx $http_*name* variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_)

> $http_name: arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores

`$http_host` should therefore contain the request 'Host' header, if that helps.

e.g. localhost:8020

Comment: It worked, thank you! Here is the final solution: `error_page 497 https://$http_host$request_uri;`

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty much a duplicate of this one:

[How to forward non-http requests on port 80 to another port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/857766/how-to-forward-non-http-requests-on-port-80-to-another-port)

There they receive non-HTTP requests on port 80, you get non-HTTPS requests on a port 443 alternative. Other than that, the idea is the same.

Nginx modules exists to do more with TCP packets:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html

https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module

Comment: Not really, it's not just a simple redirect, let me explain: I request the url `https://localhost:8443/` from my browser and this request get forwarded to my VM's port 443 where it get handled. But if I use HTTP, then the url is `http://localhost:8443/` and it hits the server on the port 443. So if I use the `$server_port`, then I get redirected to `https://localhost:443`. Additionally, as it's a VM, I can't be sure that it's always port 8443 so I can't hardcode it but I have to parse it from the request somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A user named @wilee mentioned that they found wilee's solution helpful. They stated that their Nginx service was configured to listen on port 80 in the Docker container. However, when they ran the Nginx container, they mapped port 8000 to port 80. Initially, they used the following configuration:

```
error_page 497 https://$host:$sever_port$request_uri;
```

This resulted in redirects from

- `http://192.168.0.38:8000`
  to
- `https://192.168.0.38:80`.

After making changes to their configuration as follows:

```
error_page 497 https://$http_host$request_uri;
```

They were able to resolve the issue and the configuration worked as expected.

Comment: Please review grammar (maybe run it through ChatGPT or other LLM to improve the English). Thanks for the answer.